# pueden ver porque falla mi código ?? me da error CS0161 CS1525 Y CS0029

Tags: c#

Tengo este código y me da fallo, tampoco se si lo he escrito bien, se supone que debo de tomar el valor del parámetro de entrada, crea la secuencia Fibonacci, que se compondrá de tantos elementos como indique el valor de “numero” y se retorna el array con la secuencia Fibonacci generada.

este es el código de la parte de la secuencia de fibonachi y la de retornar el array.

```
public static int[] SecuenciaFibo(int numero)
{
        int[] sec_fibo = new int [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811];

        for (int i = 0; i < numero; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(int [i]);
        }
    }
```

He probado a reescribir uel código, pero soy novata y no se muy bien como hacerlo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No nos hagas googlear los errores. Agregalos a la pregunta, asi vemos mas facil que tipo de errores te da y podemos ayudarte mejor

Comment: igual, esto int[i] no existe.. habras querido poner el nombre del array ahi?

Comment: Y tranquilamente este codigo te va a dar un outofbounds error si numero es mas grande que tu array...

Answer (score 0):

Por partes:

1.- Para declarar un array con sus datos, la sintaxis es:

```
int[] sec_fibo = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811 };
```

Fijate en las llaves y corchetes.

En la próxima versión de C# (C#12) que viene dentro de días, podrás hacer también:

```
 int[] sec_fibo = [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811];
```

2.- Tu quieres retornar un `array`, para esto puedes crear uno auxiliar y llenarlo con los datos

```
 public static int[] SecuenciaFibo(int numero)
 {
     int[] sec_fibo = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811};
     int[] auxiliar = new int[numero];

     for (int i = 0; i < numero; i++)
     {
         auxiliar[i] = sec_fibo[i];
     }
     return auxiliar;
 }
```

O simplemente usar `Range`

```
public static int[] SecuenciaFibo(int numero)
{
    int[] sec_fibo = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811};
    return sec_fibo[..numero];
    //return sec_fibo[0..numero]; //Esto es lo mismo de arriba, y entrega un sub array de 0 a "numero"

}
```

---

Por último, creo que es evidente que no es la manera de retornar la secuencia de fibonacci. Este ejercicio es muy común en la programación, y la idea es que escribas el algoritmo, tu básicamente estas haciendo "trampa" al escribir la secuencia fija.